# Are "bestellen mit" und "bestellen bei" the same?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

I don't quite get the differences between these two words. Could somebody explain it to me, please. They are all about ordering something by something. And that is the point where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bestellen mit**

is »to order with«:

> Walter **bestellt** einen Hotdog **mit** Ketchup.
>   Walter **orders** a hotdog **with** ketchup.
>
> Lisa **bestellt** einen Computer **mit** einer Maus.
>   Lisa **orders** a computer **with** a mouse.
>
> Mario **bestellt** eine rote Jacke **mit** großen Knöpfen.
>   Mario **orders** a red jacket **with** big buttons.

---

**Bestellen bei**

is »to order at«:

> Walter **bestellt** einen Hotdog **bei** einem Hotdogverkäufer.
>   Walter **orders** a hotdog **at** a hotdog seller.
>
> Lisa **bestellt** einen Computer **bei** Müllers Elektronikladen.
>   Lisa **orders** a computer **at** Müller's electronic shop.
>
> Mario **bestellt** eine rote Jacke **bei** seinem Schneider.
>   Mario **orders** a red jacket **at** his tailor.

Comment: Danke schön 